# PHP: How can get the folder upload url

Tags: php, url

I have folder that save all file i upload it, Now i save in this folder all PDF and Docx file.

We need now to show it in Google viewer like :-

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<? echo $docx; ?>&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

This viewer need url of file, So i save the upload folder in root  like :-

```
index.php
single.php
upload/
  -filename.pdf
```

The url of file :- `www.domain.com/upload/filename.pdf`

How can i get the folder url like `www.domain.com/upload/`

Comment: its get me link like f:// from localhost .. i need localhost not f://

Answer (score 1):

Try [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) as the following

```
$file = "http//".$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]."/upload/file.pdf";
echo dirname($file); // output ->  localhost/upload
```

Comment: when i test it in local host i canot get only localhost

Comment: Do you want `ServerName(ex: localhost)` only, or `ServerName with dirname(ex: localhost/upload)` ?

Comment: dirname(ex: localhost/upload)

Comment: OK, what's wrong now. the code above does what you want. I have tested and the output is `localhost/upload`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$str = "www.domain.com/upload/filename.pdf";
$parts = explode("/",$str,3);
echo $parts[0]."/".$parts[1]."/";
```

Comment: Looool :) i need the $str ?? how can i get it

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.